# How to check Glassfish4 server is overloaded?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, servlet-filters

My java web application runs on Glassfish4. I want to show a webpage have the string - Server too busy. Please try again later.

Which solution is the best for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a Filter class. In Filter class, I check JVM memory status to redirect server busy page.

Comment: Could you provide more details?